# xmlHTTP SCRIPT5: Access is Denied error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

Have an error which I am unable to overcome. It involves reading a local file. Code is below, works completely in Chrome. On IE10,  it works with jQuery and not with xmlHTTP. The xmlHTTP route will give a `SCRIPT5: Access is Denied` error.

I don't see any cross domain action within the code, but to ensure flexibility I altered the security setting to allow cross domain code, but was still unable to execute it properly. Turning to you all for your expertise with many thanks!

The external reference is `test.txt` which is a simple file sitting in the same directory with this HTML file and contains one line of text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function getXmlHttp() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }
   if (xmlhttp == null) {
      alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
   }
   return xmlhttp;
}


function readFileHttp(fname, callback) {
   xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 ) { 
          callback(xmlhttp.responseText); 
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", fname, true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function handleTextFile(e){
   var strOutput = String(e);
   var result = document.getElementById('xmlHTTPText');
   result.innerHTML = strOutput;
}

function doXMLHTTP(){
   readFileHttp("./test.txt", handleTextFile);
}

function handleJQTextFile(e){
   var strOutput = String(e);
   var result = document.getElementById('jQueryText');
   result.innerHTML = strOutput;
}

function doJQuery(){
   $.get("./test.txt", handleJQTextFile);
}

</script>
<button onclick="doJQuery()">doJQuery</button>
<button onclick="doXMLHTTP()">doXMLHTTP</button>
<BR />
<A>jQueryText:&nbsp;</A><A id="jQueryText"></A>
<BR />
<A>xmlHTTPText:&nbsp;</A><A id="xmlHTTPText"></A>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I took your example and tested it on Win8/IE10 and it worked without errors http://cl.ly/image/31062p1N3v0o Is there something I am missing? Were you using IE10preview on Win7 perhaps?

Comment: Is this link helpful to you 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/get-the-internet-explorer-script-error-which-says/be14db88-0ace-4771-a5d0-7754be69a98e?msgId=2561b6be-86c2-4b3f-8790-66dbd9cea4c9

Comment: Thanks Elijah. I never did figure it, so living with the jQuery route.

Comment: Thanks Prabu, I saw that one before and did not get it working after following those steps. I am using jQuery still.